# Dropdown menu behind text

Tags: css, z-index

I tried to create a drop down menu. That's what I did so far:
http://gegensinn.org/test.html
(I made the drop down menu visible at all time for "debugging")

I think the problem is quite obvious: The menu is behind the text.

First I thought I could fix this with z-index.

Although I'm not quite sure which element has to get the z-index property.

I tried to set the whole menu to `z-index:100;` and at the same time set the `z-index:1;` of  `.main`.

Afterwards I tried to set only the z-index of `<li>` and  `<a>` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `position:relative` on `#header` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think applying z-index like so should work.

CSS

```
#menu a
{
  z-index: 100;
}

#menu ul li ul
{
  position: absolute;
}

#main
{
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Some browsers ignore z-index if it is not set on both elements in question.

Answer (score 0):

add position relative to **li** and position absolute to **sub ul** and then **z-index**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue, just add `!important` and the `z-index` to the menu/header area:

```
position:relative !important;z-index:999
```